# How to use grep or awk to print out specific chunks?

Tags: awk, scripting, grep, ksh

I want to print out a chunk of a text file with a specific start and end pattern.

For example file.txt has

```
Start X1
 <stuff_for_x1>
END

Start Y1
 <stuff_for_y1>
END

Start X2
 <stuff_for_x2>
END
```

and I want my output to be:

```
Start X1
 <stuff_for_x1>
END

Start X2
 <stuff_for_x2>
END
```

in which all the chunks begining with "Start X" and ending with "END" are printed.

I have no idea how to approach this. Your help will be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to select all lines between one starting with (`^`) "Start X" and "END"

```
awk '/^Start X/,/^END/' file.txt
```